# gestureResponseDistance seems not work in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to increase de gestureResponseDistance using different ways to improve the swipe gesture back, but none of mi attempts works:

**1. Changing gestureResponseDistance inside the createStackNavigator: Try A**

`

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: {
      screen: Drawer
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
    navigationOptions: params => ({
      gestureResponseDistance: {
        horizontal: 200
      }
    })
  }
);
```

`

**2. Changing gestureResponseDistance inside the createStackNavigator: Try B**
`

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: {
      screen: Drawer
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
    navigationOptions: {
      gestureResponseDistance: {
        horizontal: 200
      }
    }
  }
);
```

`

**3. Adding defaultProps to the stack navigator variable:**
`

```
AppNavigator.defaultProps = {
  gestureResponseDistance: 200,
};
```

`

**4. Adding prop to the stack navigator tag**
`

```
return (
  <Root>
    <AppNavigator gestureResponseDistance="200" />
  </Root>
);
```

`

Any idea?, thanks.

Comment: BTW, this is the Expo version of my app example with the same issue https://snack.expo.io/@gersonmontenegro/gestureresponsedistance-test